# How do I put subtitles on plotly with subtitles with table

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I essentially want to know how to put a title on the example on the url:

https://plot.ly/python/table-subplots/

under the section:
Table and Right Aligned Plots

There is three charts and one table, how do I add subplot titles?

I have only gotten xaxis titles to work and when I try to reposition the xaxis my graph aspect ratio is broken and xshit doesnt work either.

Comment: May you please attach a screenshot of your present situation, so we know where you need the (sub)titles as well as your present code. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this to your layout definition. See [this example](https://plot.ly/~PlotBot/922/multiple-subplots-with-titles/#plot) to reference and further insight to ease your implementation:

```
    "annotations": [
      {
        "text": "Plot 1"
      },
      {
        "text": "Plot 2"
      },
      {
        "text": "Plot 3"
      }
    ]
```